# Remove for loops to make it faster - numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have this python code using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
table = np.array([[23, 54, 12], 
                 [17, 32, 25],
                 [43, 19, 11],
                 [31, 22, 10],
                 [21, 19, 35]])
r, c = table.shape
out = np.zeros((r,c)) 
out[0, :] = np.cumsum(table[0,:])
out[:, 0] = np.cumsum(table[:,0]) 

for j in range(1, c):
    for i in range(1, r):
        out[i,j] = max( out[i-1,j], out[i,j-1] ) + table[i,j]

out[-1,-1]
```

I first calculate the 1st row and the 1st column of the array 'out', while the rest of the values are calculated with the equation inside the for loops. I am interested only on the last value of the table ( out[-1,-1] ) and I want to make it as fast as possible. Could I remove the two 'for' loops somehow??

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully to make it recursive but I still think it won't be fast like that. I really need to make it as fast as possible

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to think from another users perspective, who doesn't know _anything_ about your problem, which might be for days or weeks now in your head. So, [mcve] and [ask] apply here. I'd like to state that your code doesn't even run, because you forgot the outer brackets in your table definition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in effect finding the longest path from each coordinate to 0,0, where the cost is given by the table for each node on the path. The standard 'matrix way' to deal with such problem is Floy-Warshall algoritm, which makes n matrix multiplications, where n is the number of nodes, in your case r*c. Your algorithm is actually already optimized variant of Floyd-Warshall that uses the fact that every path that goes from (i,j) to (0,0) must pass either (i-1,j) or (i,j-1).

This is already a huge optimization!

I don't think there is a way to deal with this without an iteration over all the coordinates.

But maybe you could use some graph library to encode it as a graph problem, which would push the iteration part into the (efficient) graph library.

EVEN BETTER:

You could iterate over diagonals, using fill_diagonal for instance. This way ou would iterate only over the number of diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish.

You're making a new `out` array that copies the first(0th) row and column from the original table. (By the way, at `out[:, 0] = np.cumsum(table[:,0])`, you overwrite the element at `[0, 0]`).

You then proceed to filling the rest of the `out` array by taking the the maximum of either the element in the row before or that of the column before.

You're then adding the contents of the original array `table` at that spot to the maximum.

Since you're looking for previous rows and columns in the `out` array, you'll often find yourself in a situation where you've overwritten those values before you check them. 
For instance, when you're at `i=2, j=1`, you've got the array

```
[[ 23.  77.  89.]
 [ 40. 109.   0.]
 [ 83.  *?*   0.]
 [114.   0.   0.]
 [135.   0.   0.]]
```

You're at the `*?*` and checking for 109 and 83. And you've just inserted 109 in the previous iteration.

Thus, you are unable to get the same result without the use of those for loops.

Comment: I only want the last value of the table, not the entire table. I also don't change the element at [0,0], although I overwrite it, it has the same value anyway since it's cumsum of 1st element